# SignalR Invoke() method "Unauthorized" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have added SignalR to our existing asp.net web application and everything is working fine.  I've published this web application to Azure and now I'm getting Unauthorized error on the invoke method.
I've enabled web sockets and ARR affinity on Azure.
I'm not using Authorize attribute.
Do I need to add something else to my application to authenticate the web app or the user?

StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Date: 
  Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=MyAppx.azurewebsites.net
  WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="MyAppx.azurewebsites.net" authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/authorize" resource_id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 58
  Content-Type: text/html
}

Comment: I've added this to my Startup method GlobalHost.HubPipeline.RequireAuthentication() and this to my hub connection connection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials.  Still getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because support for SignalR in asp.net is limited you must use some of the .net core libraries.Instead of using the invoke() method on the hub connection, you can take advantage of var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext() which will eliminate a lot of pluming code. Using GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext solved the authorization issue as well.